# Generating a 1D cellular automata in Python

Tags: python, performance, cellular-automata

I wrote a program that generates a set of [1D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_cellular_automaton) [cellular automaton](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryCellularAutomaton.html). Basically, it generates this (rule 150):

[image: simple triangle]

...and rotates it to form this:

[image: simple square]

I then introduced an element of randomness to it, so it could form images like this:

[image: complex square]

I was hoping I could get reviews for the code I have, focusing around how to optimize it and improve its performance. This program feels like it takes a second or two to generate a 511x511 square on my machine, which makes it feel a bit laggy.

Here's the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Code that will generate a fractal or a pseudo-random fractal
based on an initial seed and any acceptable 1-d cellular automata
algorithm.
'''
import sys
import random
import time
import pygame

class Rules(object):
    '''Contains a variety of rules that determines if a cell should turn black 
    based on the cells in the row above. Each function is namespaced inside 
    the 'Rules' class for convenience.
    '''
    @staticmethod
    def rule150(above):
        '''Colors a cell black if there is an odd number of black cells 
        above it.'''
        return sum(above) in (1, 3)

    @staticmethod
    def rule150randomized(above):
        '''Colors a cell black if there's an odd number of black cells above it 
        (although this rule will be ignored 0.05% of the time.'''
        if sum(above) in (1, 3):
            return random.randint(0, 2000) != 0
        else:
            return False

class Generator(object):
    '''An object which generates a single wedge based on an initial seed
    and a rule. If the seed is `None`, a random one will be generated.'''
    def __init__(self, seed=None, rule=Rules.rule150):
        self.seed = seed
        self.rule = rule

    def _generate_seed(self, seed=None):
        '''Takes a seed and converts it into an integer.
        If the seed is `None`, a random seed based on system time
        will be generated.'''
        to_int = lambda item : int(''.join([str(ord(x)) for x in str(item)]))
        if seed is None:
            return to_int(time.time())
        elif type(seed) in (int, long):
            return seed
        else:
            return to_int(seed)

    def _calculate_row(self, previous_row):
        '''Generates the next row based on the previous row.'''
        def _above(row):
            previous_row = [False, False]
            previous_row.extend(row)
            previous_row.extend([False, False])
            for i in range(len(previous_row) - 2):
                yield previous_row[i: i+3]

        return [self.rule(i) for i in _above(previous_row)]

    def generate(self, n=None):
        '''Yields n rows.'''
        row = [True]
        yield row
        if n == None:
            while True:
                row = self._calculate_row(row) 
                yield row
        else:
            for i in xrange(n - 1):
                row = self._calculate_row(row)
                yield row

    def create_grid(self, n):
        '''Returns a `Grid` object containing a wedge that
        has been rotated four times to form a square.
        The generated wedge will be `n` rows long, yielding
        a square of size `n * 2 - 1`'''
        size = n * 2 - 1
        grid = Grid(size, size)
        # Takes raw coordinates and returns new ones 
        # based on the center of the grid.
        x = lambda raw_x: grid.center[0] + raw_x
        y = lambda raw_y: grid.center[1] + raw_y

        grid.seed = self._generate_seed(self.seed)
        random.seed(grid.seed)

        for index, row in enumerate(self.generate(n)):
            for i, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell:  
                    raw_x = index
                    raw_y = i - index
                    # Rotates a wedge four times to form a square.
                    grid.set(x(raw_x), y(raw_y))
                    grid.set(x(-raw_x), y(-raw_y))
                    grid.set(x(-raw_y), y(raw_x))
                    grid.set(x(raw_y), y(-raw_x))
        return grid

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''A convenience function to create a grid.'''
        return self.create_grid(*args, **kwargs)

class Grid(object):
    '''An object which holds an arbitrary grid of pixels.'''
    def __init__(self, x, y, seed=None):
        self.width = x
        self.height = y
        self.array = []
        # The seed used to generate the grid.
        self.seed = seed
        for i in xrange(self.height):
            self.array.append([False for i in xrange(self.width)])

    @property
    def center(self):
        '''Gets the center of the grid. Assumes the height and 
        width are odd.'''
        return (int(self.width / 2), int(self.height / 2))

    def get(self, x, y):
        return self.array[y][x]

    def set(self, x, y, value=True):
        self.array[y][x] = value

class PygameRenderer(object):
    '''Renders a grid object using Pygame, and also contains code to
    save the current grid.'''
    def __init__(self, n, pixel_size, 
                    background=(255, 255, 255), foreground=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.pixel_size = pixel_size
        side_length = n * 2 - 1
        self.size = (side_length * self.pixel_size, 
                     side_length * self.pixel_size)
        self.background = background
        self.foreground = foreground

        self._configure_pygame()
        self._configure_graphics()

        self.grid = None

    def _configure_pygame(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
        self.surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

    def _configure_graphics(self):
        self.tile = pygame.Surface((self.pixel_size, self.pixel_size))
        self.tile.fill(self.foreground)

    def render(self, grid):
        '''Renders the grid, and prints the current seed to stdout.'''
        self.grid = grid
        self.surface.fill(self.background)
        for x in xrange(self.grid.width):
            for y in xrange(self.grid.height):
                if self.grid.get(x, y):
                    self.surface.blit(
                        self.tile,
                        (x * self.pixel_size, y * self.pixel_size)
                    )
        pygame.display.flip()
        print self.grid.seed

    def wait(self):
        while True:
            event = pygame.event.poll()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    def refresh(self):
        '''Waits until Pygame is closed. Clicking any keyboard
        button will save the current image to the current directory,
        and clicking the mouse will break from the mainloop so that
        the containing function can create a new grid.'''
        while True:
            event = pygame.event.poll()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                return # Returns so that a new grid can be generated.
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                filename = str(self.grid.seed) + '.png'
                pygame.image.save(self.surface, filename)

class AsciiRenderer(object):
    '''Creates an ASCII version of the grid.'''
    def to_string(self, grid):
        out = []
        for x in xrange(grid.width):
            row = ['[']
            for y in xrange(grid.height):
                if grid.get(x, y):
                    row.append('#')
                else:
                    row.append(' ')
            row.append(']')
            out.append(''.join(row))
        return '\n'.join(out)

    def render(self):
        print self.to_string()


def test_rows(n=5):
    '''Tests generating a series of rows.'''
    g = Generator()
    for index, row in enumerate(g.generate(n)):
        padding = " " * (n - index - 1)
        out = "[{0}{1}{0}]"
        print out.format(padding, "".join("#" if n else " " for n in row))

def test_grid(n = 5, pixel_size = 16, rule=Rules.rule150):
    '''Creates a normal grid.'''
    grid = Generator(rule=rule)(n)
    r = PygameRenderer(n, pixel_size)
    r.render(grid)
    while True:
        r.refresh()

def test_grid_randomized(n=256, pixel_size=1, rule=Rules.rule150randomized):
    '''Creates a randomized grid, and will repeatedly create a new one.'''
    g = Generator(rule=rule)
    r = PygameRenderer(n, pixel_size)

    while True:
        grid = g(n)
        r.render(grid)
        r.refresh()

def generate_single_random_grid(n=256, pixel_size=1, 
            rule=Rules.rule150randomized, seed=None):
    '''Creates a randomized grid.'''
    grid = Generator(rule=rule, seed=seed)(n)
    r = PygameRenderer(n, pixel_size)
    r.render(grid)
    r.refresh()

def profiling_test(n):
    Generator(rule=rule)(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #test_rows()
    #test_grid(16, 4, Rules.rule150)
    test_grid_randomized(256, 1, Rules.rule150randomized)
    #profiling_test(256, 1, Rules.rule150)
```

---

**Some specific questions I have:**

This specific code I'm using to render each square:

```
def render(self, grid):
    '''Renders the grid, and prints the current seed to stdout.'''
    self.grid = grid
    self.surface.fill(self.background)
    for x in xrange(self.grid.width):
        for y in xrange(self.grid.height):
            if self.grid.get(x, y):
                self.surface.blit(
                    self.tile,
                    (x * self.pixel_size, y * self.pixel_size)
                )
    pygame.display.flip()
    print self.grid.seed
```

It basically iterates through a 2D array (the `grid` object), and blits a tile to the surface if the given cell should be black. Is there any way to optimize this method? I feel I shouldn't be blitting so much, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

This is the code I'm using to generate the actual rows (see the 1st picture):

```
def _calculate_row(self, previous_row):
    '''Generates the next row based on the previous row.'''
    def _above(row):
        previous_row = [False, False]
        previous_row.extend(row)
        previous_row.extend([False, False])
        for i in range(len(previous_row) - 2):
            yield previous_row[i: i+3]

    return [self.rule(i) for i in _above(previous_row)]

def generate(self, n=None):
    '''Yields n rows. If n is None, this will yield an infinite amount of rows.'''
    row = [True]
    yield row
    if n == None:
        while True:
            row = self._calculate_row(row) 
            yield row
    else:
        for i in xrange(n - 1):
            row = self._calculate_row(row)
            yield row
```

Similarly, is there any way to optimize this and make it faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warning: this hasn't been rigorously tested (*i.e.*, with a known seed)!

There are a couple of things that can be tried without majorly changing things:

1. Grid.center - you already know what it is on initialisation, so create a normal variable for it and remove the @property version. This avoids calculating it several hundred thousand times.

   ```
   self.center = (int(x / 2), int(y / 2))
   ```
2. Enumerate over the array/columns when displaying as you do in other places. This will stop you doing an list index that's repeated:

   ```
   def render(self, grid):
       '''Renders the grid, and prints the current seed to stdout.'''
       self.grid = grid
       self.surface.fill(self.background)
       for x,col in enumerate( grid.array ):
           xc = x * self.pixel_size
           for y,cell in enumerate( col ):
               if cell:
                   self.surface.blit(
                       self.ftile,
                       (xc, y * self.pixel_size)
                   )
       pygame.display.flip()
   ```
3. The lambdas in Generator.create_grid can be removed (function calls)

   ```
   xc,yc = grid.center
   for index, row in enumerate(self.generate(n)):
       raw_x = index
       for i, cell in enumerate(row):
           if cell:  
               raw_y = i - index
               # Rotates a wedge four times to form a square.
               grid.set( xc + raw_x, yc + raw_y )
               grid.set( xc - raw_x, yc - raw_y )
               grid.set( xc - raw_y, yc + raw_x )
               grid.set( xc + raw_y, yc - raw_x )
   ```
4. Changing the rules. rather than doing `sum(above) in (1,3)`, why not explicitly state the combinations?

   ```
   black_set = ( [False, False, True], [False, True, False], [True, False, False], [True, True, True] )
   ...
   if above in Rules.black_set:
       #etc
   ```

All these might give you ~60-65% of the original.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Applying these brought the time of a single trial run from about 2.25 seconds (discounting pygame's initialization) down to about 1.25 seconds.